# Bundle succeeds but doesn't load all gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, dependency-management

I am inheriting a Rails application and I'm having problems getting the app running.  As I would except there is a .rvmrc, Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in the repo which - in my mind - should allow me to resolve all dependencies properly.

When I run **bundle install** everything seems to get installed correctly, but when I run **bundle console** I get an error that nokogiri cannot be loaded:

```
/Users/MyUser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@appname/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
```

I find this incredibly confusing - how is it possible that bundler loads all the requirements as specified in the Gemfile.lock and the doesn't find them?  It doesn't seem to be a problem with a specific gem either - when I comment out the gem in question it simply seems to fail on the next one (unfortunately this app requires around 200 gems).

If I do run **bundle show nokogiri** it spits out the correct path.  How do I get to the root of this problem?  I've never had issues with bundler so I am really stumped as to what the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this issue by making sure all local gems are uninstalled and then running **bundle install --path vendor/bundler**

Still no idea what was wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

Does "bundle exec rails console" work?